# React-overlays Affix doesn't work inside a scrolling element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm using AutoAffix (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/react-overlays/#affixes) inside an `overflow: scroll` container, and it doesn't update its position at all. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/blob/master/src/Affix.js#L36), it appears that they only set a listener on the window itself, so it doesn't fire when my div is being scrolled - and I don't see any parameters that would change this behavior.

Is there any way to make it work in this case?